# How do you construct the URL to access a google docs/drive folder?

Tags: php, http, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to make a [raw request to Google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to [access a public folder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-eVxZFKAu61TmFQUUFPbzBmVVU).

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=0B-eVxZFKAu61TmFQUUFPbzBmVVU&key=__________
```

However, that URL gives the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

Which tells me that perhaps I'm not supposed to pass the ID of the folder inside `q=`.

On a related note, I know you can access individual public files with a request like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=_____
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that you have passed an invalid value for the `q` parameter.  The `q` parameter receives a combination of fields, values and operators.  You passed the the folder id through `q`, but you didn't specify which field to match that id with.

What you need to pass to `q` is `'0B-eVxZFKAu61TmFQUUFPbzBmVVU' in parents` (don't leave out the single-quotes!).  So, your query would look like: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='0B-eVxZFKAu61TmFQUUFPbzBmVVU'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.

Check out [this API page](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) to learn more about the format to use for `q`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following value for q: `trashed=false and title contains 'Public Folder'`

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) say that the field `title` is the `Title of the file`. However I remember that you could also use this for searching on folder names.

You might also want to optimize your search by including the mimeType field. From the docs:

> Search for folders using the folder-specific MIME type:
>
> `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`

*EDIT* - It seems that google drive is having problems at the moment, try something like this tomorrow:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title contains 'Public Folder' and trashed=false&mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: The request seems to fail for me: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%22trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20title%20contains%20%27Public%20Folder%27%22&key=____`. Also, I am not using the SDK, just trying to access it raw.

Comment: Have you tried accessing: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=yourapikey, this returns a 500 internal error for me - which I assume is because google drive has problems at the moment.